# Regex to find field, subfield, operator and value from where criteria of custom query expressions

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-group

I have sample where clause for our custom NoSql solution, as below

`Name.Contains('between') and (DateField in ('2020-12-01', null)) And Name = 'test' and Product.Name != 'P1'`

where I need to find all condition groups and for each of them want to detect left field, operators and value to transform them to MySql syntex

1. `Name.Contains('between')` => `Name`, `Contains` and `'between'`
2. `(DateTimeField in ('2020-12-01', null))`  => `DateField`, `in` and `'2020-12-01', null`
3. `Name = 'test'` => `Name`, `=` and `test`
4. `Product.Name != 'P1'` => `Product.Name`, `!=`, `P1`

here field can be with our without dot (.) notations e.g. `Name`, `Product.Name` etc...

Also, operation can be with or without dot (.) notations, e.g. `.Contains`, `.StartsWith`, `In`, `!=`, `=` etc...

Only values with `StartsWith|EndsWith|Contains|In` are going to be in braces, and other will be in single quotes

I managed to have 2 separate regex, one for In and one for other operators, but its not working as expected for combination and overlapping scenarios

Regex for In pattern : `@"(?:\b(?:\w+)\.)?(\w+)\s*(\b(?:IN)\b)\s*\(([^)]+)\)"`, here not able to detect field with dot notation

2nd regex for other operators :  `@"(\b(?:\w+)\.)?(\b(?:Contains|StartsWith|EndsWith)\b)\(([^)]+)\)"`, this one is detecting field with dot notation upto one level only

I'm looking for single/multiple regex to suffice all above mentioned scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

to detect fields with many levels, use this regex:
`((?:\w+(?:\.\w+)*)|\w+)\b(?<!\.(?:Contains|EndsWith|StartsWith))`

to detect the operators [only what mentioned in the question], you can use the following:
`((\.(?:Contains|EndsWith|StartsWith)|\sIn\s)|(\s*!=\s*)|(\s*=\s*))`

to detect the values:
`\('([^']+)'\)| \(([^()]+)\)`

Comment: This is invalid regex, with negative lookbehind

Comment: Actually, this only for detecting fields with multiple levels, as Product.Name
the negative lookahead to except the words operators.

Comment: review the edited answer. every part of condition group has its own regex. may you can recombine them. I think that what you try to do?